# Firebase push data Swift?

Tags: swift, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I know for the web Firebase API there is a `.push()` option that will guarantee the entries will be in the order they were inserted into your database. However, using Swift the only way to add data is to use the `.set()` and `.updateChildValues()` methods.

Is there anything like the `.push()` for Swift where I can make sure my data appears in the order it was inserted?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In iOS the method to generate such unique keys is called `childByAutoId()`.

See the [Firebase documentation on adding an item to a list](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data#append_to_a_list_of_data).